# Python3 time.sleep() behaving erratically

Tags: python-3.x, sleep

L.S,

i am trying to learn python(3) and am baffled by the behavior of time.sleep()
i run raspbian buster on a rpi3b.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import bluetooth
import sys
import time
_shuttermac ="11:22:33:44:5D:6A"
while True:
    # check if the device is switched on by mac address lookup
    print("Checking " + time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S - ", time.gmtime()),end ="")
    result = bluetooth.lookup_name(_shuttermac, timeout=5)
    #print(result)
    if (result != None):
        print("Device detected by bluetooth mac lookup")
    else:
        print("Device with MAC " + _shuttermac + " NOT detected")
    time.sleep(1)   # check every 5 secs if device comes online      
sys.exit()
```

output

```py
Checking Thu, 25 Jun 2020 11:21:02 - Device with MAC 11:22:33:44:5D:6A NOT detected
Checking Thu, 25 Jun 2020 11:21:08 - Device with MAC 11:22:33:44:5D:6A NOT detected
Checking Thu, 25 Jun 2020 11:21:14 - Device with MAC 11:22:33:44:5D:6A NOT detected
Checking Thu, 25 Jun 2020 11:21:20 - Device with MAC 11:22:33:44:5D:6A NOT detected
Checking Thu, 25 Jun 2020 11:21:26 - Device with MAC 11:22:33:44:5D:6A NOT detected
```

as you can see, the output statement is **6** seconds apart, not **1** as coded

where did i go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The six second interval comes because each loop of `while True` does two time-consuming things when the lookup fails:

1. `bluetooth.lookup_name(_shuttermac, timeout=5)` has a 5 second timeout. If it is found quickly, it should complete faster
2. `time.sleep(1)` pauses the whole Python program for 1 second

You could shorten the timeout on `bluetooth.lookup_name` and the `sleep()` duration. This *may* have unintended consequences in the accuracy of the lookup (I'm not very familiar with it).